# Got permission denied while trying to connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: ros, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the docker using the docker installation page. After installing the docker, I have tried the Case 1 and clone the docker repo. When I ran the command './run.sh', I am getting the following error. Please help.

*Using options:
ROS distro: melodic
Image name: autoware/autoware
Tag prefix: latest
Cuda support: on
Pre-release version: off
UID: <1000>
Launching autoware/autoware:latest-melodic-cuda
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344052/got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-docker-daemon/) by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@dynamicsoorya have you added your user to the `docker` group as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)?

Otherwise it looks like you'll need to modify the `run.sh` file to call `sudo docker` instead of just `docker`

---

Originally posted by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) with karma: 166 on 2020-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-02-18**:
@sgermanserrano
Yes, that definitely worked. Thank you very much for your help. I have added my user to the docker this way:

sudo usermod -aG docker your-user

And that worked.

Thanks a lot!